# GCP datastoreにjournalファイルのような仕組みはありますか

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud

タイトルの通りですが

GCPのdatastoreを使って開発していますが
ある操作以前へのRestoreのようなことをどうやって実現すれば良いのかわかっていません。
(手動でのチェックポイントのBackup/Restore機能があるのは把握しています。)

GCP datastoreに操作履歴の確認やログからのある時点への状態復旧のようなことはできますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現状、Google Cloud Datastoreにそのような機能はありません。